# C# NPOI read EXCEL cells from top to bottom

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, xls, npoi

I have sequence for reading EXCEL sheet from left to right

```cs
for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
    if (row == null) continue;
    if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
    for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
    {
        if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetCell(j).ToString()) && 
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetCell(j).ToString()))
            {
                rowList.Add(row.GetCell(j).ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I am getting all the text from 1st sheet, but I need to read each column from top to bottom.

Here's what I tried but it's ending up getting 1 word loop from random cell...

```cs
for (int i = headerRow.FirstCellNum; i < headerRow.LastCellNum; i++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
    if (row == null) continue;
    if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
    for (int j = sheet.FirstRowNum; j <= sheet.LastRowNum; j++)
    {
        if (row.GetCell(i) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetCell(i).ToString()) && 
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetCell(i).ToString()))
            {
                rowList.Add(row.GetCell(i).ToString());
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read each column from top to bottom you call `row.GetCell(i)` in the second `for` loop instead of `row.GetCell(j)`.

```
for (int i = headerRow.FirstCellNum; i < headerRow.LastCellNum; i++)
{
    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
    if (row == null) continue;
    if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
    for (int j = sheet.FirstRowNum; j <= sheet.LastRowNum; j++)
    {
        if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.GetCell(j).ToString()) && 
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.GetCell(j).ToString()))
            {
                rowList.Add(row.GetCell(j).ToString());
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```